# MINUS Operator in CAML

Tags: caml

I need to use MINUS Operator in my CAML Query. Is it available in CAML? Looking for answers.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you provide your sample code that you've tried?

Comment: How exactly are you planning to use it?

Comment: I am planning to retrieve list items from two different lists .The condition is based on MINUS Operator.I meant What are the list itmes not in my second list whcih is in first list .I need to display those list itmes.So only i am looking for MINUS Operator.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a custom code solution, then you can calculate value in your code, and use it in your CAML query.